# Find Bayesian estimator for $e^{\theta}$

Tags: bayesian, estimators, conjugate-prior

> Given $\{Y_i\}_n\sim U(\theta-1,\theta+1)$ and prior distribution $\theta\sim U(a,b),1\leq a<b$
> is the posterior distribution conjugate? Find the absolute error estimator for $e^{\theta}$ and credible interval.

I've found that $\pi(\theta|Y)=(\frac{1}{2})^{n}(\frac{1}{b-a})\mathbb{I}\{max(Y_{max}-1,a)\leq\theta\leq min(y_{min}+1,b)\}$ I think that the posterior is conjugate when $Y_i$ are given but not sure about how to find the estimator.

Comment: Are you asking which point estimate minimises the expected absolute error? This would be the median of the posterior distribution for $e^\theta$, but note that $e^\theta$ is an increasing function of $\theta$, making the calculation very easy

Comment: @Henry Yeah, I know it's the median but didn't know how to calculate it

Comment: That is where my note comes in.  You can take the midpoint of your posterior uniform distribution (average of the end points) as $\hat \theta$ and then $e^{\hat \theta}$ will be the median you want